# Entity Framework query table name dynamically based on input parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-4

I have been working in a project which uses Entity Framework as the ORM data model to connect to the SQL database and retrieve data.

Now the basic query which is used to retrieve data is like this

```
ProjectDataContext dataContext = new ProjectDataContext();   

var result = (from project in dataContext.Projects
              select project).ToList();
```

Or in lambda

```
List<Project> lstprojects = dataContext.Projects.Take(10);
```

Now I would like to pass the table name dynamically based on some input parameter. How can I achieve that?

The way I am currently doing it is a bit messy.

```
if(tableName = "A")
{
     List<A> lstOfA = dataContext.A.Take(10);
}
else if(tableName = "B")
{
     List<B> lstOfB = dataContext.B.Take(10);
}
```

and so on...

My question is if there is a neat and clean way to do this without writing so many if else because I understand it may cause performance issues in future.

Thanks

Comment: Your first LINQ snippet is effectively `dataContext.Projects.ToList()`, there's no need for the `select project` portion. As to your question, you need to realize that Entity Framework is there (mostly) to *abstract away* the database and lets you manipulate data in terms of C# types instead of database tables. If you'll pass a `<T>` to your method instead of `tableName` string, you'll be able to call `dataContext.Set<T>()` and get your desired `DbSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after some trial and error I have been able to do it like this-

```
var type = Type.GetType("A");
context.Set(type).Load();
var result = context.Set(type).Local.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Hope it helps.`

Comment: `GetProjects<Type.GetType("A")>` does not compile

Comment: @Backs changed appraoch